# How to add app-links on a Meteor-cordova project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I have a Meteor 1.8.1 which uses Cordova 7.1.4 for Android build. 
I want to add app-links so that when a user clicks on a `myApp.com` link the app is open instead of the browser.

I have added the following to mobile-config.js:

```
App.appendToConfig(`

<platform name="android">
  <config-file target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_myApp" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_myApp">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.myApp.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
          <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myApp.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </config-file>
</platform>
`)
```

When I try to compile the APK I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 1s
27 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 23 up-to-date
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While building Cordova app for platform Android:
   Error: /home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
   /home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:100: AAPT: error: unexpected element <intent-filter>
   found in <manifest><application>.

   /home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:111: AAPT: error: unexpected element <intent-filter>
   found in <manifest><application>.

   /home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:130: AAPT: error: unexpected element <receiver> found
   in <manifest><application><activity>.

   /home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:100: error: unexpected element <intent-filter> found
   in <manifest><application>.
   /home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:111: error: unexpected element <intent-filter> found
   in <manifest><application>.
   /home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:130: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in
   <manifest><application><activity>.
```

Generated `/home/meteor/myApp/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp.app"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="10003"
    android:versionName="1.0.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!-- for android -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> -->
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> -->
    <!-- for Samsung -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" /> <!-- for htc -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" /> <!-- for sony -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" /> <!-- for apex -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" /> <!-- for solid -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" /> <!-- for huawei -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> <!-- for ZUK -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" /> <!-- for OPPO -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> <!-- for EvMe -->
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.myApp.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.myApp.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myApp.app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/activity_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.myApp.app.permission.PushHandlerActivity" />

        <receiver android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.BackgroundActionButtonHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushDismissedHandler" />

        <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.FCMService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true" />

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_myApp" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.myApp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_myApp" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.myApp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="myApp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name="com.myApp.app.ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_myApp" >
            <receiver
                android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
                android:exported="true" />

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_myApp" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.myApp.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="myApp.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
         FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.myApp.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
 FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myApp.app.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `meteor reset` which typically fixes these issues. It does the same thing as deleting the .meteor/local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with the files on my `.meteor/local` folder, deleted it, removed and added android platform and now it compiles correctly.